# HTML - how to find and replace text

Tags: html

I am just using basic HTML - with no Javascript, XML, CSS etc. I would like to find the instances of "--" and replace them with an 'em dash'. My code so far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<center>
<head>
    <title>TREASURE ISLAND</title>
</head>

<header>
    <h1>TREASURE ISLAND</h1>
    <h3>by Robert Louis Stevenson</h3>
    <h3>PART ONE--The Old Buccaneer</h3>
    <h4>Chapter 1--The Old Sea-dog at the Admiral Benbow</h4>
</header>
</center>

<body>
"Fifteen men on the dead man's chest -- Yo-ho-ho, and a bottle of rum!"
</body>

<Style>
Body {
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
}
<Style/>

</html>
```

I have searched "find and replace, HTML" on Google but all the results talk about using Java. Can anyone offer some hints on how to achieve this, or improve my code in general?

Comment: using what to replace

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically on your page (you need JS) or you just need  to parse/transform this HTML once? Please explain further what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: everything you enter in HTML is converted into DOM (Document Object Model) and to acess anything in DOM dynamically you need JS. Simply put you cannot do this with pure HTML

Comment: These are my instructions for the code "File treasure.html contains some ‘--’ symbols representing points where an ‘em dash’, i.e., ‘—’, should appear if the document is properly typeset.  Replace these with the proper em-dash symbol, which in HTML mark-up notation is ‘&mdash;’." So I just want to run some function to find the "--" in the text and then run another function to replace it with "—". It's just a 'find this word and replace it with this word' kind of operation, but I am not sure how to do it in HTML

Comment: Any text editor have `replace` function. If you have multiple documents then you just need more advanced editor. Netbeans maybe?

Comment: Do you think they mean simply find and replace the text using the editor? If so then I can do that no worries. I thought there was some way of coding in HTML to find words in text and then replace them. (I guess that is what you were referring to when you said dynamically Samuil?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question states you are not using JavaScript and not that you do not want to use it.

I don't see how this can be done without some kind of DOM manipulation which is beyond the scope of basic HTML.

If you are willing to use JavaScript you can simply add this code to your webpage.

```js
(function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("Body").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("--", "—");
  document.getElementById("Body").innerHTML = res;
})();
```

```html
<center>
  <header>
    <h1>TREASURE ISLAND</h1>
    <h3>by Robert Louis Stevenson</h3>
    <h3>PART ONE--The Old Buccaneer</h3>
    <h4>Chapter 1--The Old Sea-dog at the Admiral Benbow</h4>
  </header>
</center>

<section id="Body">
  "Fifteen men on the dead man's chest -- Yo-ho-ho, and a bottle of rum!"
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a homework exercise and I am starting to think they just meant use the text editor to find words and replace them as we aren't expected to know Javascript yet. But this is good to know.

Comment: @user88720 sorry but what kind of a homework is that ? I highly suspect that's what they want unless it's an "IDEs" class which I highly doubt

Comment: It's an introductory IT course at uni. It's the first week of HTML and we are to format the first page of a book properly so it shows on a webpage. I can find and replace text in a document using Python and I thought they wanted us to do the same here, but yes I am pretty sure now they just wanted us to use the editor to do it, rather than code some function.